# Setting Up ACRA to log crashes in android application

Tags: android, acra

I am new into android application development. I was reading an article about setting up acra on server and client (android application ). 
I found something like this in [tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-and-use-acra-android/en).

First of all, login into the system with your administrator account set previously.

Now we are going to install an acro-storage (Acralyzer's Storage Endpoing). From the right menu, press Replicator and fill in the form from Remote Database and to Local Database like this:

```
from Remote Database: http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acra-storage
to Local Database: acra-myapp
```

Press Replicate and wait until it is done.
Next install Acralyzer with the same method but different parameters.

```
from Remote Database: http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acralyzer
to Local Database: acralyzer
```

Press Replicate to install.

So my Ques are

- Why is the remote database used ?
- Will my logs be send to remote database as well ?

Answer (score 1):

`Replicate` is basically copy'n'paste for databases. As Acralyzer runs directly in the database, this is basically the installation, which copies files to their target folder.

> Why is the remote database used ?

The remote database is the template for all installations.

> Will my logs be send to remote database as well ?

No.